# Using Powershell to Loop check usernames from csv, loop through AD and add a number if needed

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

Here is my scenario,

I wrote a SQL query that extracts user accounts with a null username from our student information system. Lets just assume these are newly enrolled students. I then want to take this list, which has a column of suggested usernames, done by simple concatenation in the SQL query. I want to loop through that csv and check to make sure that username doesn't already exist in AD , if it does, append the next available number to the username.

So in my test environment I have a csv that looks like this. ( I made this up for testing)

> StudentID,First,Last,SuggestedUsername
>
> 12345,tony,Test,testto
>
> 54321,tolly,test,testto

I my test AD environment I already have a student named Tommy Test or Testto, so in this case, my powershell script should tell me Tony Test should be testto1 and Tolly Test should be testto2. Is this making sense?

The meat of my script works, It will read the csv, loop through AD and return testto1 for line 1 of the csv, the problem is it will not read line 2, the script ends

I have been playing around with the arrays in the script but here is what I have so far

```
 Import-module Activedirectory

 Add-Pssnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.admanagement

 $useraccounts =@()

$useraccounts = import-Csv "Path\Test.csv"

$userbase = Get-QADuser -sizelimit 0 -SearchRoot 'mydomain.com/OU'

foreach ($user in $useraccounts) {

if ($userbase)

   {

       $userbase = $userbase | Select samaccountname | %{($_ -split "@")[0]}

       $UserNumbers = @()

       $userbase | % {

           if ($_ -Match '\d+')

               {

                   $UserNumbers += $matches[0]

               }

    }

        $MaxUserNumber = ($userNumbers | Measure-Object -max).Maximum

        $suggestedUserName = $user+($MaxUserNumber+1)

    }

  Else

    {

        $SuggestedUserName = $user

    }

    }

    Write-Host $suggestedUserName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, your loop doesn't appear to be cycling because you aren't using an array of strings as your output, you are just using a string, so it just shows up with the last loop. But if you like my solution that's neither here nor there, because I think I have a better option for you. Just for the sake of simplicity, back up your CSV and then delete the Suggested Name column and run this against that.

```
$Users = Import-CSV "path\test.csv"
$Users|%{$_|Add-Member UserID ("$($_.last)$($_.first.substring(0,2))")}
$NameConflicts = $Users|group userid|?{$_.count -gt 1}
ForEach($Name in $NameConflicts){
    $x=0
    if(dsquery user -samid "$($name.name)*"){
        $x = Get-ADUser -Filter {samaccountname -like "$($Name.Name)*"}|%{$_.samaccountname -replace "($($Name.name))(\d*)","`$2"}|sort -Descending |select -first 1
    }
    For($i=if($x -gt 0){0}else{1};$i -lt ($Name.count);$i++){
        $Name.Group[$i].UserID = "$($Name.Name)$($i+$x)"
    }
}
$Users|group userid|?{$_.count -eq 1}|%{if(dsquery user -samid "$($_.name)"){$_.Group[0].UserID = "$($_.Name)1"}}
$Users|FT -auto
```

That loads your list, creates potential user names by taking the last name and the first two letters of the first name. Then it groups by that, and finds any of them that have more than one. Then for each of those it checks AD for any existing accounts with names like that, and takes the number off the end of the name, and selects the highest one. Then if it found any already in existence it renames all of the potential user names to append the next available number to the end (if none are found in AD it leaves the first one, and renames the rest of them). Lastly it checks all of the other names, where there is just one user name, and if it is in AD already it adds a 1 to the end of the user id.

This should run faster than your script, because I'm only searching for names that are needed to be checked, and it's filtering at the provider level instead of taking all names, and then filtering through powershell.

Comment: This is beautiful, much much faster than what I was going. I have 2 options from here, pipe to New-ADuser or just create a csv from this output and use that to import usernames and create accounts.